# Google Selector API Fails When Logged in with More Than 1 Google Accounts in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-picker, google-apps-script-api

I am using the The Google Picker API in an Apps Script project and it works well. However, when I am logged in with more than 2 Google accounts, the The Google Picker API fails. I think this is because it confuses the sessions of one account with another and permissions.

I got the code from google's official documentation [Apps Script Example The Google Picker API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#dialog.html).

in the code.gs file I have the following code

```
/**
 * Creates a custom menu in Google Sheets when the spreadsheet opens.
 */
function onOpen() {
  try {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Picker')
        .addItem('Start', 'showPicker')
        .addToUi();
  } catch (e) {
    // TODO (Developer) - Handle exception
    console.log('Failed with error: %s', e.error);
  }
}

/**
 * Displays an HTML-service dialog in Google Sheets that contains client-side
 * JavaScript code for the Google Picker API.
 */
function showPicker() {
  try {
    const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dialog.html')
        .setWidth(600)
        .setHeight(425)
        .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select a file');
  } catch (e) {
    // TODO (Developer) - Handle exception
    console.log('Failed with error: %s', e.error);
  }
}

/**
 * Gets the user's OAuth 2.0 access token so that it can be passed to Picker.
 * This technique keeps Picker from needing to show its own authorization
 * dialog, but is only possible if the OAuth scope that Picker needs is
 * available in Apps Script. In this case, the function includes an unused call
 * to a DriveApp method to ensure that Apps Script requests access to all files
 * in the user's Drive.
 *
 * @return {string} The user's OAuth 2.0 access token.
 */
function getOAuthToken() {
  try {
    DriveApp.getRootFolder();
    return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  } catch (e) {
    // TODO (Developer) - Handle exception
    console.log('Failed with error: %s', e.error);
  }
}
```

in the dialog.html file I have the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
  <script>
    // IMPORTANT: Replace the value for DEVELOPER_KEY with the API key obtained
    // from the Google Developers Console.
    var DEVELOPER_KEY = 'ABC123 ... ';
    var DIALOG_DIMENSIONS = {width: 600, height: 425};
    var pickerApiLoaded = false;

    /**
     * Loads the Google Picker API.
     */
    function onApiLoad() {
      gapi.load('picker', {'callback': function() {
        pickerApiLoaded = true;
      }});
     }

    /**
     * Gets the user's OAuth 2.0 access token from the server-side script so that
     * it can be passed to Picker. This technique keeps Picker from needing to
     * show its own authorization dialog, but is only possible if the OAuth scope
     * that Picker needs is available in Apps Script. Otherwise, your Picker code
     * will need to declare its own OAuth scopes.
     */
    function getOAuthToken() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPicker)
          .withFailureHandler(showError).getOAuthToken();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Picker that can access the user's spreadsheets. This function
     * uses advanced options to hide the Picker's left navigation panel and
     * default title bar.
     *
     * @param {string} token An OAuth 2.0 access token that lets Picker access the
     *     file type specified in the addView call.
     */
    function createPicker(token) {
      if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            // Instruct Picker to display only spreadsheets in Drive. For other
            // views, see https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#otherviews
            .addView(google.picker.ViewId.SPREADSHEETS)
            // Hide the navigation panel so that Picker fills more of the dialog.
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            // Hide the title bar since an Apps Script dialog already has a title.
            .hideTitleBar()
            .setOAuthToken(token)
            .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
            // Instruct Picker to fill the dialog, minus 2 pixels for the border.
            .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2,
                DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
            .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
      } else {
        showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
      }
    }

    /**
     * A callback function that extracts the chosen document's metadata from the
     * response object. For details on the response object, see
     * https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/result
     *
     * @param {object} data The response object.
     */
    function pickerCallback(data) {
      var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];
      if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
        var url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        var title = doc[google.picker.Document.NAME];
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
            '<b>You chose:</b><br>Name: <a href="' + url + '">' + title +
            '</a><br>ID: ' + id;
      } else if (action == google.picker.Action.CANCEL) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Picker canceled.';
      }
    }

    /**
     * Displays an error message within the #result element.
     *
     * @param {string} message The error message to display.
     */
    function showError(message) {
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + message;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button onclick="getOAuthToken()">Select a file</button>
    <p id="result"></p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

when the dialog box appears, it asks me for permission to access google drive, it shows me that I am in the first account, when in fact I want to access from the 2nd account, I change it from the user interface and it gives me an Error: NetworkError: Connection failed due to HTTP 403.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1PwR.png)
change to the second account
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiWeL.png)

my theory is that as I am running the script in the second account, for some reason it gets the access token from the first account, which does not have the required permissions, a solution I have found is to run the script from an incognito window in the browser, where I only have a single google session.